# What is a good way to allocate a sized string buffer on the stack?

Tags: c

Using pure C (and the C-preprocessor) I would like to create a string buffer that includes a length parameter, so that I could pass it around easily and any functions that operate on it could do so without danger of writing past the end. This is simple enough:

```
typedef struct strbuf_t_ {
    int  length;
    char str[1];
} strbuf_t;
```

but then if I want a small scratch space on the stack to format some output text, there is no trivial way to allocate a `strbuf_t` on the stack. What I would like is some clever macro that allows me to do:

```
STRBUF(10) foo;
printf("foo.length = %d\n", foo.length); // outputs: foo.length = 10
strncpy(foo.str, "this is too long", foo.length);
```

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to do that. The best I've come up with is:

```
#define STRBUF(size, name) \
    struct {\
        strbuf_t buf;\
        char space[size - 1];\
        char zero;\
    } name ## _plus_space_ = { .buf={.length=size}, .space="", .zero='\0'};\
    strbuf_t *name = &name ## _plus_space_.buf

int main(void)
{
    STRBUF(10, a);

    strncpy(a->str, "Hello, world!", a->length);
    printf("a->length = %d\n", a->length); // outputs: a->length = 10
    puts(a->str); // outputs: Hello, wor
}
```

This meets all of the requirements I listed, but `a` is a pointer not the structure itself, and the allocation is certainly not intuitive.

Has anyone come up with something better?

Comment: You could just declare/allocate a char array and cast that pointer to `strbuf_t *`. `len` would then be `sizeof(char_array) - sizeof(strbuf_t) - 1`.

Comment: Your way is better since it will have better alignment.

Comment: Zero-sized arrays are not standard. Use a VLA.

Comment: Good point, make it `char str[1];` and count that as your `\0`. Actually makes book-keeping easier.

Comment: Why do you make `a` is a pointer anyway? Why not just use that `struct`? Have you tried to compile? What is `zero` for? Seems to be useless.

Comment: I have compiled this, and it works. The `zero` is to 0 terminate the string if someone uses `strncpy` incorrectly (as I did in the example). Regarding the VLAs - those aren't fully standard in C11 either. Probably best to use a length of 1, then offset the length by 1

Comment: @N.Leavy: `zero` will not work. If you really forget to terminate your array, you invoke undefined behaviour if you access the array beyond its boundaries. There is no guarantee there will be no padding or nasal demons past the array..And VLAs are very well standard, even in C11! They are just optional (and yes, imo it was a stupid decission). Just use `_Static_assert(!__STDC_NO_VLA__)`. However, you propose a defintively non-standard extension over an optinal (and likely implemented one)?

Comment: `zero` does in fact work - as is shown in the example where the 10 byte string is not null terminated because strncpy doesn't always null terminate a string. It is technically undefined behaviour in that the layout of a struct is not defined, so the compiler may feel free to pad space between `space` and `zero`. But seeing a few bytes of junk at the end of a string is much better than blowing your stack.

Comment: @olaf: regarding the VLAs - I would need to define a different strbuf_t everywhere I wanted to declare one with a different size, then cast it back to a standard strbuf_t. Certainly that would be a solution to the problem, but it doesn't seem more elegant than what I have now. In any event, I removed the zero length array.

Comment: Meditate about the implications of **undefined** behaviour. Yes, that does include it might even behave as expected. But you were asking for a **standard** way, and invoking UB is exactly the opposite. Just make your functions work properly and unit-test. Btw: why do you think `zero` will be properly initialised and not overwritten if you don't trust your functions to terminate the array properly? You could as well just set the last entry to `'\0'`. That would serve exactly the same purpose, but without UB.

Comment: Bad code can *always* write past the end of the "array", even if it's passed a structure with a length. Remember that the length of a C-string can still be calculated using `strlen`, not much different from using a pre-calculated length. Also, using your structure you must reinvent *all* string functions all over from the beginning, or at least wrap them with your own functions. I simply see no reasons for these Pascal-strings.

Comment: But to answer your question in the title, how to allocate dynamically on the stack, you could search for and read about the non-standard but common `alloca` function.

Comment: @Joachim: I wasn't trying to prevent against writing beyond the end of the buffer - as you point out there is nothing much you can do for that short of playing around with memory protection. I was trying to protect against the brain dead behaviour of strncpy not always null terminating a string.

Comment: @N.Leavy: To protect against `strncpy` (I agree about its pitfalls), just write the terminator to the last entry int he array. No UB, no harm done.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If such strings are supported by a full-featured library and - possibly - the language itself, they are very well useful and often faster (no need to scan for the length). Still such buffers might be some niche application., but not useful for normal C strings. Hower, that would be useful for `malloc` & co with a _flexible array member_.

Comment: @Joachim: I'm not planning on using these to hold strings as such - but rather as a way to pass a string-buffer to a function. This way it can return a dynamic string without doing a `malloc` or using some sort of static buffer that wouldn't be thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already pretty close to a solution. Just keep a `char*` in your struct and allocate it via char-array. In order to have the save trailing zero at the end of string, just allocate an extra char additional to the size and initialize the whole array with zeroes.

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    char* str;
} strbuf_t;

#define STRBUF(varname, size) \
    char _buffer_ ## varname[size + 1] = {'\0'}; \
    strbuf_t varname = { size, _buffer_ ## varname }

int main()
{
    STRBUF(a, 10);

    strncpy(a.str, "Hello, world!", a.length);
    printf("a.length = %d\n", a.length);
    puts(a.str);
}
```

Comment: Don't use double leading underscore in names, those are reserved in all scopes for the compiler and standard library.

Comment: Ok, gonna rename it. Sometimes I'm thinking to much in compiler terms while still playing in manual written code :)

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg Just to add, (because I wanted to know who is doing the reserving), "... All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use...." C11 §7.1.3 1

Comment: @chux puh, close call... I nearly ended up using another reserved name, but fortunately the `_buffer...` starts lowercase

Comment: Note:  the next line of the spec is "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  If I read that right `STRBUF(a, 10);` is ok in `main()`, but _maybe_ a problem as a global. IDK.

Comment: I like this - much simpler than what I was doing. I was trying to keep it all in one structure which was definitely overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following.  Allocate the memory with an aligned VLA and then overlay.

```
typedef struct strbuf_t_ {
    int  length;
    char str[];
} strbuf_t;

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s = "Hello";

  size_t length = strlen(s);
  size_t n = sizeof (strbuf_t) + length + 1;
  _Alignas(strbuf_t) unsigned char mem[n];

  strbuf_t *xx = (strbuf_t*) mem;
  xx->length = length;
  memcpy(xx->str, s, n+1);

  printf("int:%zu s:%zu n:%zu mem:%zu\n", 
      sizeof xx->length, sizeof (strbuf_t), n, sizeof mem);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
int:4 s:4 n:6 mem:10
```

Note: C99 allows the last `struct` member to have an indefinite array count of `[]`